# Парсинг HTML

Tags: php

Есть html вида:

```
<div>
    <h2><a href="...">text1</a></h2>
    <div>
        <p>text2</p>
        <p>
            <i>text3</i>
            <i>text4</i>
        </p>
    </div>

<div>
```

Код phpQuery:

```
// выше заселектили самый первый div
foreach (pq($dom)->find('*') as $d) {
    PR(pq($d)->html());
}
```

На выходе:

```
<a href="...">text1</a>
---
text1
---
<p>text2</p>
<p>
    <i>text3</i>
    <i>text4</i>
</p>
---
text2
<i>text3</i>
<i>text4</i>
---
text3
text4
```

Т.е. phpQuery рекурсивно лезет во все теги, выдавая мне одну и туже строку с текстом по несколько раз.  
Нужно, чтобы на выходе было только:

```
<a href="...">text1</a>
---
<p>text2</p>
<p>
    <i>text3</i>
    <i>text4</i>
</p>
```

Т.е. чтобы он не выдавал мне всё в рекурсии, а проходился только по первым тегам в диве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как в jQuery:

так:

```
pq($dom)->children()
```

или так:

```
pq($dom)->find('> *')
```

Comment: спасибо добрый человек, я думал уже крышка алгоритму